# Can you construct a simple bipartite graph G, that has $\kappa (G) < \lambda(G) < \delta(G)$?

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

Is it possible to construct a simple bipartite graph G, that has $\kappa (G) < \lambda(G) < \delta(G)$ ?

Where $\kappa (G) $ is vertex connectivity, $\lambda (G)$ is edge connectivity.

I can find examples where $ \kappa (G) \le \lambda (G) \le \delta(G)$ holds, like $K_1,_2$

But I am struggling to find a example where the strict inequality holds but it doesn't feel impossible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: Let $G_1$ and $G_2$ be disjoint copies of $K_{3,3}$. Let $v$ be a new vertex not in $G_1$ or $G_2$. Connect $v$ to two vertices of $G_1$ and to two vertices of $G_2$ to form $G$.

Comment: @K.Hal: Make sure that both vertices in $G_1$ to which you connect it are in the same part of $G_1$, and both vertices of $G_2$ to which you connect it are in the same part of $G_2$. Those parts of $G_1$ and $G_2$ will be one part of $G$.

Comment: excuse me sir, i know this question is asked 3 months ago. but would you mind proving that this method always works? for example, if $\kappa(G)=3$,$\kappa'(G)=4$ and $\delta(G)=5$ ...